# Is it possible to conditional format a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to conditional format a column before or after i write it to csv or excel file. I have a dataframe with 2 columns.The dataframe is saved on my desktop named 'DPMO.csv' I want to conditional format the DPMO column before i save it. Is it possible to do so?

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\\Users\Username\Desktop\DPMO.csv, index = False)
Managers    DPMO
John        55240
Ron         23514
Mary        12541
Young       25587
Anna        65841
```

Comment: What do you mean by "conditional format?" What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to color code the DPMO column based on the value. Similar to excel conditional format

Comment: [xlsxwriter conditional formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html)